# White bar on right hand side of page

Tags: html, css

I recently built this website using HTML, CSS, CSS3 and Bootstrap however I keep finding this white bar on the right hand side of the page and I cant get rid of it. Could anyone take a look at it, if possible? 
Website: http://www.faisalpatel.co.uk/

Comment: It would be better if you had a fiddle.  And I don't see a white bar in Firefox.  Which browser are you viewing it in?

Comment: Cannot reproduce at any size in Chrome

Comment: Works fine for me too! what browser are you using?

Comment: you guys aren't checking the scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have row `.row` inside an element without any padding to accommodate for the negative margin a row gives you

```
.row {
   margin-right: -15px
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Its in both your header and you footer.  You need to a `container` class or add the padding to those elements `padding: 0 15px;` to accommodate for the row used in them and any other element you have that just a ROW in it without an element around it that has the padding to offset it

Comment: looks like you'll need to update your header, footer, #Projects, #Contact